# Detect UILocalNotification close button pressed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

How can I able to work on close event of the UILocalNotification in Objective-C ?
Or I can detect Notification has finished ?
How can I modify this code to code in close button ?

```
localNotification.alertBody=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpdict objectForKey:@"Reminder"]];

NSDictionary *snoozeDic=[tmpdict objectForKey:@"Snooze"];
if ([[snoozeDic valueForKey:@"Switch"]intValue]==1) {
    localNotification.alertAction=@"Snooze";
} else
{
    localNotification.hasAction=NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the Close button action. After scheduling a LocalNotification it becomes a System event, and you can only access the "view" event with "didReceiveLocalNotification"

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
        didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Believe me, I wish it was not the case...